# IntelliJ Manage clipboard history

Tags: intellij-idea, clipboard

Is it possible to manage the entries created within the IntelliJ History clipboard and that we can consult using command "CMD+Shift+V" ?

Why: This is because I see a lot entries which are polluting the history when text is copied

Example - Paste from history

```
1 ~/Library
2 ~/Librar
3 ~/Libra
4 ~/Libr
5 ~/Lib
6 ~/Li
7 ~/L
8 ~/
9 ~
....
```

[image]

Best

Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the **Copy to clipboard on selection** option at File | Settings | Tools | Terminal:

[image: Copy to clipboard on selection]

Entries in the history dialog can be removed using the <kbd>Del</kbd> key. You can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Arrows or <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse clicks to select multiple entries before the deletion.